# HAProxy and reqrep path rewriting with redirect configuration

Tags: regex, redirect, url-rewriting, haproxy, httpbackend

With HA Proxy 1.5 I need to rewrite URL from
`http://main.domain.com/my-foo`
to
`http://othersite.com:8081/other-bar`

Here is what I tried:

```
frontend ft_def
  bind :80                                      
  mode http                                                  
  acl has_special_uri path_beg /my-foo
  use_backend def if has_special_uri
  default_backend def

backend def
  mode http                                       
  option forwardfor                       
  reqirep ^([^\ ]*\ )/my-foo(.*)    \1/other-bar\2
  server myserver othersite.com:8081
```

This works:
URL
`http://main.domain.com/my-foo/home.html`
becomes
`http://othersite.com:8081/other-bar/home.html`

and in the browser the initial URL `http://main.domain.com/my-foo/home.html` appears.

It is exactly what I need: it is completely transparent for the user.
But redirect does not work: when I click on a link on the page the URL is then
`http://main.domain.com/other-bar/page2.html`

I would like to get `http://main.domain.com/my-foo/page2.html` instead appearing in the browser.

Is it possible with HA Proxy? I tried many configurations without success.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about links in HTML (as opposed to, say, `Location:` headers for redirects)... HAProxy 1.5 won't be able to modify those.

Presumably, based on what you describe, the page `/other-bar/page1.html` is internally linking to `<a href="/other-bar/page2.html">` when it really should link to `<a href="page2.html">`.  You'd need relative links in order for something like this to work transparently... otherwise, component "X" in your chain will have to be able to modify links on the fly in the response body, but only links, of course, since you wouldn't want to blindly regex-replace the page contents as a whole... and HAProxy 1.5 doesn't munge response bodies, so it can't fulfill the role of component "X."

HAProxy 1.6 *might* be able to do this, with Lua, but that's a maybe... and if it can be made to do it, it isn't likely to be at the level of performance you'd typically expect from HAProxy, because scrubbing the html in Lua is probably going to be a relatively expensive proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Normally any URL changes should be handled by the web app itself, e.g. there is a `:path` option under `:url` configuration in `Phoenix.Endpoint` for the Phoenix framework: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html, which was specifically designed for this purpose. Then the browser will still request the URL appears in the HTML file but HAProxy will always rewrite it.